# Xamarin reverse geocoder - multiple addresses

Tags: ios, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

I am working on an iOS project using Xamarin. I am wondering is it possible to use Xamarin.Forms.Maps.GeoCoder to retrieve a list of addresses based on GPS coordinates. I am using the method GetAddressesForPositionAsync but it is returning just one address. I need to allow users to select an address from a list of possible addresses based on their current location. 
I tried using the CLLocationManager property desiredAccuracy in an attempt to increase the radius and hopefully return a list of multiple addresses but unfortunately this simply made the one address returned less accurate.

Does anyone know if it is possible to return all addresses within a 100m radius of a users current coordinates using geocoder?

Any help would be really appreciated thanks!

Comment: `Xamarin.Forms.Maps.GeoCoder` using `CLGeocoder` and that connects to Apple location services, typically you are only going to get just the "best" hit based upon the how specific the location is, even at a "city level", you might only get two or three addresses (typically major landmarks). You might want to look at `MKLocalSearch` : https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mapkit/mklocalsearch

Comment: @SushiHangover thanks very much, I'll look into MKLocalSearch and see if it's what i'm after. Is it possible to tell it to search for everything nearby when setting the natural language query on the MKLocalSearchResult?